# Repeat Question from Unity Answers

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, site-recommendation

If I ask a question on Unity Answers, is it acceptable to also ask that same question on Stack Overflow?  If so, under what circumstances:

- Only if nobody on Unity can answer it?
- Simultaneously, because the are separate sites?
- Only if I can rephrase the question to not be Unity specific?
- Never, ever, ever unless pigs fly?

Specifically, I am referring to [this question](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/833118/coroutine-in-extension-method.html), which I think may have some trouble on Unity Answers, but is very Unity specific.

Comment: If it is unity specific wouldn't the gamedev SE be appropriate? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TimSeguine not sure, but I've always thought of SO as the place for code, while GD is better for everything else game related. I would like to know tho...perhaps I'll ask that question after rereading the site descriptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter whether you've already asked a question on X or Y site. This is Stack Overflow and if your question is [within the scope of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) you're more than welcome to ask it.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: Unity Answers does not belong to the SE Network and thus the "crossposting is meh!"-rule does not apply ;)