# Should unity3d related tags and questions be migrated for ease of access?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

There are other questions surrounding this topic:

[Replace the misleading [unity] tag with a more distinct tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269701/replace-the-misleading-unity-tag-with-a-more-distinct-tag)

[Repeat Question from Unity Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276951/repeat-question-from-unity-answers)

[Do we need Unity questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314906/do-we-need-unity-questions)

And there are many more. But I can't find any question discussing moving the tag to a more relevant community like the [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) community.

Stack Overflow have over 40k questions on **unity3d** tag, while Game Development only have over 10k questions on **unity** tag.

When I read [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) tagged questions I often see questions on functionality related to the game engine and/or unity classes and their functions. They are often very similar to questions that are asked on Game Development.

Since the scripting language is in C#, the questions are sometimes tagged with [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Most of those questions are not as much C# related as they are unity-unique functions. Previous Unity versions also use a really old C# and .NET version which makes it harder to find solutions that works with Unity's C# version.

The main points of my question is:

- Is it not an inconvenience having to move between communities when
  trying to find a solution to a problem?
- Are tags used alongside with unity3d tag dirtied with irrelevant questions?
- Can questions tagged with unity3d get better answers from a community with users that face the same problems more often/at all?
- Should we migrate correctly tagged questions to a more relevant community?

I'm not asking if we should remove questions with these tags. I'm asking if it wouldn't be better to have similar questions (currently divided between different communities) in the same community.

Comment: First of all: you can't *move* a tag between SE sites. Second: all that matters is scope: When a question is on-topic on a specific site, it can be asked there and it is fine to have and keep it there. That premises doesn't change if other sites will accept that same question. In other words: the scope of one site isn't influenced by the scope of another site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it not an inconvenience having to move between communities when trying to find a solution to a problem?

Not if people are aware that there is another community.

> Are tags used alongside with unity3d tag dirtied with irrelevant questions?

That would require a complete overhaul of the tag. Currently [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) has 47,674 questions. This same question could be asked of any tag.

> Can questions tagged with unity3d get better answers from a community with users that face the same problems more often/at all?

Stack Overflow has the most visit per day, in fact it's in the top 100 sites visited per day on the internet. It's hard to compete with that. Although a community dedicated to gaming would be concentrated with experts in that area.

> Should we migrate correctly tagged questions to a more relevant community?

Not if they are on topic for Stack Overflow. I decline many migration requests wanting post to go to another site that may well be on topic for the   other site. If they are on topic for Stack Overflow they stay. Please read [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

> I'm not asking if we should remove questions with these tags. I'm asking if it wouldn't be better to have similar questions (currently divided between different communities) in the same community.

Having multiple communities wor. Many people favour the smaller network sites, some people prefer Stack Overflow. If anything, having two sites increases the library of work.

Comment: Sound reasonable to me, marked as answer.